# How to map Cognito (federated) identity ID to Cognito user pool ID?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm trying to map a Cognito user pool ID to a cognato federated identity ID and I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's what I'm trying to do : 
- a user login to a user pool
- he drops a file on s3 with the path ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}
- then I need to do processing on that file, for which I need to retrieve the user's pool ID

I've searched extensively and I can't find a way to access the user pool Id which is different than the identity ID.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to direct way map a Cognito `User Pool ID` with a Cognito `Identity ID`(for an Identity in the Identity Pool).

However, as a workaround, you could store the mapping in a Cognito User Pool `Custom Attribute`, or any RDBMS/NoSQL Database.

Comment: Any idea how I could achieve that ?

Comment: For more information about Custom Attributes, look into this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure this out as well, looks like the folks serverless-stack.com have this figured out!

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html

Sample lambda code for a lambda that's authorized through IAM that extracts the user pool user id.

```
export async function main(event, context, callback) {
  const authProvider = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider;
  // Cognito authentication provider looks like:
  // cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx,cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_aaaaaaaaa:CognitoSignIn:qqqqqqqq-1111-2222-3333-rrrrrrrrrrrr
  // Where us-east-1_aaaaaaaaa is the User Pool id
  // And qqqqqqqq-1111-2222-3333-rrrrrrrrrrrr is the User Pool User Id
  const parts = authProvider.split(':');
  const userPoolIdParts = parts[parts.length - 3].split('/');

  const userPoolId = userPoolIdParts[userPoolIdParts.length - 1];
  const userPoolUserId = parts[parts.length - 1];

  ...
}
```